# Installing MariaDB - Unmet dependencies, Depends: mariadb-server-10.0

Tags: server, apt, package-management, mysql, dependencies

So I decided to upgrade from MYSQL Server to Mariadb. I thought basic un installing mysql server and installing mariadb would be swift.

When I tried installing through the commands: `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

followed by: `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db`

followed by:

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu precise main'`

and then: `sudo apt-get update`

then finally: `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`

I am getting an error:

```
`invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (= 10.1.16+maria-1~trusty); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
 mariadb-server
```

I have tried purging mariadb to revert to mysql server but can not install too. Tried a couple of fixes from the internet but can not fix this. What could be the problem? Anyone? Trust me I have googled and tried a lot of fixes but can not work?

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is below

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
#deb http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main
#deb-src http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) and you have added repository for Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) ?

```
deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu precise main
```

If I run search for mariadb on packages.ubuntu.com, there is mariadb already in trusty universe repositories - see this [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mariadb&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Can you remove http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu repository in /etc/apt/sources.list and check if there are some  strange repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list.d. ?

After that purge previous mariadb installation and try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

This will install maria db 5.5. If you need version 10.1 try with official instructions [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=crete&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty&version=10.1).

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to deal with unmet dependencies is to use Synaptic Package Manager. 

0] Install it if you don't have it yet. 
Link:
1] Click on Settings>Filters. Go to broken and check not installable and broken.
2] Custom filter using Broken to package mentioned in error. 
3] Right click > Mark for complete removal.
4] Click Apply on the top bar.

That should solve it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late but had the same issue last night as well after upgrading MariaDB to 10.1 stable, on Linux Mint 17.2 -Rafaela.

So after uninstalling + purging MariaDB, installed  10.0 stable version from  Mint 17.1 instructions, no issues.

Official Instructions [MariaDB Download Distros](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories)